# Cannot instantiate a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have an Interface

```
public interface ICrypto<T> : IDisposable
{
     ICryptoTransform GetDecryptor();

     ICryptoTransform GetEncryptor();

     T GetAlgorithm();
}
```

I have an implementation

```
public class TripleDESCryptoProvider : ICrypto<TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider>
{

    public TripleDESCryptoProvider() { }

    public ICryptoTransform GetDecryptor()
    {
        return GetAlgorithm().CreateDecryptor();
    }

    public ICryptoTransform GetEncryptor()
    {
        return GetAlgorithm().CreateEncryptor();
    }

    public TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider GetAlgorithm()
    {
     ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

i have a class that implements implementation above

```
public class CryptoWork<T> where T : ICrypto<T>, new()
{
    protected static T _keyStore;

    public static T KeyStore
    {
        get
        {
            if (_keyStore == null)
            {
                _keyStore = new T();
            }
            return _keyStore;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt a byte array
    /// </summary>
    public string Encrypt(string input)
    {
        byte[] inputArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        using (var encryptor = KeyStore.GetEncryptor())
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypt a byte array
    /// </summary>
    public string Decrypt(string input)
    {
        byte[] inputArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
        using (var encryptor = KeyStore.GetDecryptor())
        {
            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length));
        }
    }
}
```

I am having problem instantiating class `CryptoWork<T> where T : ICrypto<T>, new()`:

Neither

```
 var cryptoWork = new CryptoWork < ICrypto < TripleDESCryptoProvider > > ();
```

nor

```
var cryptoWork = new CryptoWork < TripleDESCryptoProvider > ();
```

compiles.

Comment: Well, say what "having problem" means. Paste the *exact* compiler error or failure indicator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have specified:

```
CryptoWork<T> where T : ICrypto<T>, new()
```

and you are using

```
new CryptoWork<TripleDESCryptoProvider>();
```

For that to work, we would need:

```
TripleDESCryptoProvider : ICrypto<TripleDESCryptoProvider>
```

(since `T`=`TripleDESCryptoProvider`)

But you have:

```
TripleDESCryptoProvider : ICrypto<TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider>
```

and a public parameterless constructor (which you have). Options:

- make `TripleDESCryptoProvider : ICrypto<TripleDESCryptoProvider>`
- refactor the API
- make the `CryptoWork` type have 2 generic type parameters; one for the `TripleDESCryptoProvider`, another for the `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider`